# How can I use compression forces in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, physics-engine

I'd like to use compression forces to keep detached objects suspended in the air.  Here's a photo of what I'm trying to accomplish: [image: Unity Scene view]

Ideally, they would stay in the position illustrated above until acted upon by another force.
However, the boxes become all wonky and seemingly ignore the friction between each other.

If I put them closer together, they sort of explode in every direction, and if I put them exactly touching or further apart, they simply fall straight down.

Is this possible in Unity3d? or is this beyond the scope if the standard physics engine.

Comment: so you want to gravity doesn't affect them

Comment: Do the boxes have a physics material with high friction?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: I want gravity to affect them, just, if you pickup three sugar cubes with your fingers, the middle cube stays in place because it is squeezed between the two outter cubes.  If that makes sense?  Also, is there a summary of all the prefixed stack exchanges so that I can know which one to put what questions in?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this implemented in any physics engine without intervention through code. Basically you'll have to make the objects immovable until some event triggers them to be movable.

There's no such thing as "compression force" in physics engines. The problem here is that even the slightest compression means two bodies are intersecting (overlapping) and any rigid-body physics engine will try to resolve that by moving the bodies out of the way.

A soft-body engine would be able to cope with that, but they're special use cases and not commonly used. For instance BeamNG.drive uses a soft-body physics engine to model the deformation of cars, and that's not ideal either as you'll sometimes notice that even strong metal connections have a slight wobble to them.

You can only model this behavior in a rigid-body physics engine if you were to attach the bodies through joints to keep them suspended in air, but even so they would either be allowed to intersect (might not look good unless intersection is minimal) or they'll start moving, possibly going wild. Or like I said at the beginning, have the bodies suspended at their position - put them to sleep, make sure once one of them wakes up they all wake up. Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I hadn't heard of soft bodies, I will look into them.  I guess standard (rigid body) physics engines don't do much more than transfer force on contact and simulate some elements of friction -> is that safe to say?